# Hold execution of script

Tags: javascript, jquery

just wanted to know if it is programatically possible to halt the execution of script the   same way javascript function "confirm" does. "confirm" stops further execution of script   until user input, i want to acheieve same thing for BlockUI plugin of Jquery.

Comment: Basically what i am trying to achieve is, in BlockUI popup, i will show user some message with Ok and Cancel buttons to choose from and i should proceed with further oprations only after user clicks one of the buttons.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, you cannot.
`confirm`, like the `alert` function, is a modal dialog, which is nothing more than a  [child window that requires users to interact with it before they can return to operating the parent application, thus preventing the workflow on the application main window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window).
Javascript has no *sleep*-ing mechanism. If you want to stop the execution of a script... it's only possible by executing another script that is memory/CPU expensive (such as an infinite loop) that will freeze the browser (thus stopping the targeted script from executing), but that kind of defeats the purpose.
If you know what you want to do, you can organize your code in such a manner that you can simulate the *sleep* process.
A good way of doing that is using callbacks combined with timeouts:

```
function f1(callback){
    // do some stuff
    // decide how much you want to wait
    setTimeout(callback,how_much_you_want_to_wait);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think its possible... the best you can do is,

- show an overlay div which prevents any other user interactions on page
- show your html popup in front of the overlay
- in the code, use `callbacks` or 'jquery binders' or 'event listers' to execute the rest of the code

A rough example could be,

```
function showDialog(fn){
    $('#overlay').show()
    $('#dialog').show().click(fn); // ideally bind the click to the close button of the dialog
}
```

now, to show the dialog,

```
// code before the dial
showDialog(function(){
   // execute rest of the code
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has no `sleep` function that may be available in other languages.  The best you can do is a `setTimeout`.

You could possibly do `while true` style loop but that will just spike CPU usage which is usually not encouraged.